# How to get Stereoscopic Camera Lens Lengths attribute via Python?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I have a Python script that stores the attributes of a stereoscopic camera into a `json` file and I am having trouble storing the lens Lengths attribute. I am new to Maya and this might be a very obvious thing to ask so I appreciate any input.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 

print(cmds.getAttr("cameraMain_C0_ctl.lensLengths"))
```

I was expecting to see a value of `15` or `15mm` but I get zero.

[a screenshot of the attribute I am trying to store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sraN7.png)

Is it possible to store this value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to get the attributes (camera `shapes`):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 

focalLengthCenter = cmds.camera("stereoCameraCenterCamShape", q=True, fl=True)
focalLengthLeft = cmds.camera("stereoCameraLeft", q=True, fl=True)
focalLengthRight = cmds.camera("stereoCameraRight", q=True, fl=True)

print(focalLengthCenter, focalLengthLeft, focalLengthRight)

# Result (70.0, 70.0, 70.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick, really appreciate it, I was stuck on this for a really long time.